# How to find out what version of windows is Azure VM using, with powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

What is the command to check windows version in Azure VM. For ex Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure is not aware of the OS in your VM only os type (linux\windows). if you are using a custom image - you have to know whats inside the image. another option is to use `Invoke-AzVmRunCommand` to run powershell script inside vm that will return os version. something like `$PSVersionTable` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joyVM).StorageProfile.ImageReference`.

Comment: If a VM has customized image then only ID in being displayed, rest of the properties are blank.

Comment: @TusharRaichand How did you create the image? Capture from other VM?