# Azure computer vision not working on remote: The type initializer for 'native' threw an exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've got a setup of azure function application and azure computer vision endpoint configured. Long story short, my azure function uploads image file to blob storage and then it passes it to computer vision to analyze and tag creation. While developing function locally my azure computer vision call works perfectly fine, but once the function is deployed to cloud, computer vision is not working.

At first I wasn't sure if it's computer vision problem, but once I've separated this part of code it's clearly the issue here. When calling a computer vision endpoint it responds with "The type initializer for 'native' threw an exception." without any more information.

I've found something that it might be issue with TLS but my azure function has it set to the newest version.

thanks in advance...

I've tried to separate azure computer vision call from other code and indeed it is part causing problems. It resulted with "The type initializer for 'native' threw an exception." which I havent found any goof solution for.

Expected result is that azure computer vision analyze image properly and returns generated tags.

I'm pasting my code below:

```
public class StoreClothingItem
{
    private readonly string ContainerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName") ?? "";

    private readonly IBlobStorageService _blobStorageService;
    private readonly ITableStorageService _tableStorageService;
    private readonly IComputerVisionService _computerVisionService;

    public StoreClothingItem(IBlobStorageService blobStorageService, ITableStorageService tableStorageService, IComputerVisionService computerVisionService)
    {
        _blobStorageService = blobStorageService;
        _tableStorageService = tableStorageService;
        _computerVisionService = computerVisionService;
    }

    [FunctionName("StoreClothingItem")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        //getting file from form
        var formData = await req.ReadFormAsync();
        var file = req.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();

        //getting user's input
        var userTags = formData["weatherTags"];
        var itemName = formData["name"];
        var userTagsAsComputerVisionTags = TagsUtils.ConvertStringsToTagObjects(userTags);

        List<ComputerVisionTag> tags = userTagsAsComputerVisionTags;
        BlobServiceResponse blobResponse = null;

        //saving to blob
        try
        {  
            if(file != null)
            {
                //saving image to blob container and storage table as entry
                blobResponse = await _blobStorageService.SaveFileToBlobContainer(file, ContainerName);
                log.LogInformation($"Image {blobResponse.Name} saved on blob storage");
            }

            log.LogInformation($"There was no image to be saved on blob storage");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex.Message);
        }

        if (file != null)
        {
            //getting computer vision tags
            try
            {
                var imageUrl = blobResponse.ImageUrl;

                if (imageUrl != null)
                {
                    //analyzing image with computer vision
                    tags = _computerVisionService.AnalyzeImage(imageUrl);
                }

                tags = tags.Concat(userTagsAsComputerVisionTags).ToList().OrderByDescending(tag => tag.Confidence).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.ToString());
                log.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //saving to storage table
        ClothingItem clothingItem = new();
        try
        {
            clothingItem = new ClothingItem { Name = itemName, ImageUrl = blobResponse.ImageUrl, PartitionKey = blobResponse.PartitionKey, RowKey = blobResponse.RowKey, WeatherTags = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tags) };
            _tableStorageService.SaveItem(clothingItem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //should be standarized api response here as well
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex.Message);
        }

        //create new response object
        var response = new Response()
        {
            ResultCode = "200",
            OperationType = "Save Item",
            Item = clothingItem
        };

        return new OkObjectResult(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
    }
}
```

Below's also computerVisionService class

```
public class ComputerVisionService : IComputerVisionService
{
    private readonly VisionServiceOptions serviceOptions;
    public ComputerVisionService()
    {
        serviceOptions = new VisionServiceOptions(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VISION_ENDPOINT"),
                new AzureKeyCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VISION_KEY")));
    }

    public List<ComputerVisionTag> AnalyzeImage(string imgUrl)
    {
        using var imageSource = VisionSource.FromUrl(new Uri(imgUrl));

        var analysisOptions = new ImageAnalysisOptions()
        {
            Features = ImageAnalysisFeature.Caption | ImageAnalysisFeature.Tags | ImageAnalysisFeature.Objects,
            Language = "en",
            GenderNeutralCaption = true
        };

        using var analyzer = new ImageAnalyzer(serviceOptions, imageSource, analysisOptions);
        var result = analyzer.Analyze();
        List<ComputerVisionTag> tags = new();

        if (result.Reason == ImageAnalysisResultReason.Analyzed)
        {
            if (result.Caption != null)
            {
                tags.Add(new ComputerVisionTag
                {
                    Name = result.Caption.Content,
                    Confidence = $"{result.Caption.Confidence:0.00}",
                    Type = Enums.TagTypeEnum.Caption
                });

                Console.WriteLine(" Caption:");
                Console.WriteLine($"   \"{result.Caption.Content}\", Confidence {result.Caption.Confidence:0.0000}");
            }

            if (result.Tags != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" Tags:");
                foreach (var tag in result.Tags.Where(x => x.Confidence > 0.75))
                {
                    tags.Add(new ComputerVisionTag
                    {
                        Name = tag.Name,
                        Confidence = $"{tag.Confidence:0.00}",
                        Type = Enums.TagTypeEnum.Tag
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine($"   \"{tag.Name}\", Confidence {tag.Confidence:0.0000}");
                }
            }

            if (result.Objects != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Objects:");
                foreach (var detectedObject in result.Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"   \"{detectedObject.Name}\", Bounding box {detectedObject.BoundingBox}, Confidence {detectedObject.Confidence:0.0000}");
                }
            }

            if (result.Text != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" Text:");
                foreach (var line in result.Text.Lines)
                {
                    string pointsToString = "{" + string.Join(',', line.BoundingPolygon.Select(pointsToString => pointsToString.ToString())) + "}";
                    Console.WriteLine($"   Line: '{line.Content}', Bounding polygon {pointsToString}");

                    foreach (var word in line.Words)
                    {
                        pointsToString = "{" + string.Join(',', word.BoundingPolygon.Select(pointsToString => pointsToString.ToString())) + "}";
                        Console.WriteLine($"     Word: '{word.Content}', Bounding polygon {pointsToString}, Confidence {word.Confidence:0.0000}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return tags;
    }
}
```

Below I'm posting also whole

```
{
"ClassName": "System.TypeInitializationException",
"Message": "The type initializer for 'native' threw an exception.",
"Data": null,
"InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.TypeInitializationException",
    "Message": "The type initializer for 'Azure.AI.Vision.Common.Diagnostics.Logging.VisionEventSource' threw an exception.",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.DllNotFoundException",
        "Message": "Unable to load DLL 'Azure-AI-Vision-Native' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at Azure.AI.Common.Internal.Interop.Diagnostics.native.diagnostics_eventsource_logmessage_set_callback(IntPtr callback)\r\n   at Azure.AI.Common.Internal.Interop.Diagnostics.SetEventSourceMessageCallback(LogEventSourceMessageCallbackFunctionDelegate callback)\r\n   at Azure.AI.Vision.Common.Diagnostics.Logging.VisionEventSource..ctor()\r\n   at Azure.AI.Vision.Common.Diagnostics.Logging.VisionEventSource..cctor()",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146233052,
        "Source": "Azure.AI.Vision.Common",
        "WatsonBuckets": "AQAAAEMATABSADIAMAByADMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADcAZgBlAGIAMwBlAGQAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGUAZQBlAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "TypeLoadClassName": null,
        "TypeLoadAssemblyName": null,
        "TypeLoadMessageArg": null,
        "TypeLoadResourceID": 0
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "   at Azure.AI.Vision.Common.Diagnostics.Logging.VisionEventSource.get_Singleton()\r\n   at Azure.AI.Common.Internal.Interop.VisionSource.native..cctor()",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": null,
    "HResult": -2146233036,
    "Source": "Azure.AI.Vision.Common",
    "WatsonBuckets": "AQAAAEMATABSADIAMAByADMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADEAMAAuADAALgAyADAAMwA0ADgALgAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADcAZgBlAGIAMwBlAGQAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "TypeName": "Azure.AI.Vision.Common.Diagnostics.Logging.VisionEventSource"
},
"HelpURL": null,
"StackTraceString": "   at Azure.AI.Common.Internal.Interop.VisionSource.native.vision_source_handle_create(IntPtr& source, Utf8StringHandle optionName, Utf8StringHandle optionValue, IntPtr extra, Utf8StringHandle extraNamespace)\r\n   at Azure.AI.Common.Internal.Interop.VisionSource.CreateInternal(String optionName, String optionValue, String formatNamespace, IntPtr unsafeExtraHandle)\r\n   at Azure.AI.Vision.Common.VisionSource.FromUrl(String fileUri)\r\n   at WeatherDrobeApi.Services.ComputerVisionService.AnalyzeImage(String imgUrl) in D:\\a\\dotnet-WeatherDrobeApi\\dotnet-WeatherDrobeApi\\WeatherDrobeApi\\Services\\ComputerVisionService.cs:line 24\r\n   at WeatherDrobeApi.Functions.StoreClothingItem.Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) in D:\\a\\dotnet-WeatherDrobeApi\\dotnet-WeatherDrobeApi\\WeatherDrobeApi\\Functions\\StoreClothingItem.cs:line 83",
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": null,
"HResult": -2146233036,
"Source": "Azure.AI.Vision.Common",
"WatsonBuckets": "AQAAAEMATABSADIAMAByADMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADEAMAAuADAALgAyADAAMwA0ADgALgAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADcAZgBlAGIAMwBlAGQAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
"TypeName": "native"
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: Hi @DasariKamali, I've added my code in this question : )

Comment: and what information do you have on the exception?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz „The type initializer for 'native' threw an exception.” This is what I get

Comment: Refer to this SO for Version on [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947701/how-to-find-out-what-version-of-windows-is-azure-vm-using-with-powershell#:~:text=Azure%20is%20not%20aware%20of%20the%20OS%20in,return%20os%20version.%20something%20like%20%24PSVersionTable%20should%20do).

Comment: traceback required, not just the exception. [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've just posted the traceback

Comment: what do you notice when you read through that JSON data?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it says System.DllNotFoundException, which probably indicates that some nuget fails on restore? To be honest I’m not quite sure as I face this for the first time, everything during deploy seems fine

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz, I've googled the whole error and found it already solved on stack! :)

Comment: feel free to link that solution here. don't be afraid to flag/vote your own question to be a duplicate. SO uses "duplicate" flags for SEO. many different ways to word a question allow more people to find the solution to the same problem that may just be hard to describe in a single way.